# Why [a,b] and a+b have different values with APPEND command in My Paython Code?

Tags: python, arrays, append

I am new in Python.. But i realy confused with this problem...

**The Print Results of the last 3 lines :**

['John', 'Philiph', 'Derek', 'Melanie', 'Romy', 'Andy', 44]

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'John', 'Philiph', 'Derek', 'Melanie', 'Romy', 'Andy']

[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], ['John', 'Philiph', 'Derek', 'Melanie', 'Romy', 'Andy', 44]]

**QUESTION : **
44 is in the **t** BUT---> WHY 44 isn't in the **x**

**CODE :**

```
z=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
h=['John', 'Philiph', 'Derek', 'Melanie', 'Romy', 'Andy']
x=z+h
t=[z,h]
#print(x)
#print(t)
h.append(44)
print(h)
print(x)
print(t)
```

Comment: Because `z+h` creates a new list using concatenation, it will have a length of `len(z) + len(h)`. `t = [z, h]` creates a new list which has **exactly 2** items in it, the objects being referred to by `z `and `h`. Since `h.append` mutates that object, then this will of course be visible in `t`. But `x` on the other hand does not contain that list, so of course, there is no reason for it to be reflected in `x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

z+h will create a single list containing h and z values meanwhile the [z,h] create a list of the two lists h and z

Comment: Thanks...x=z+h is a new list... İt had beed broken from z and h

Answer (score 1):

```
t=[z,h]
```

This puts references to `z` and `h` into a list, and names that list `t`. No copies of data are made.

```
x=z+h
```

This makes a new list that's a result of adding `z` and `h`, and saves that new list into `x`. Affecting `h` doesn't affect `x` because `x` doesn't contain the original `h`; it contains copies of references to the elements `h` held. Changes made to `h` can be seen in `t` though because `t` contains a reference to the original `h`.